# .htaccess URl Rewriting Directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have small Problem in .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   index.php?urltype=$1    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?urltype=$1&url=$2    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$    index.php?urltype=$1&url=$2&pages=$3    [NC,L]  

Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# MIME types for Video
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv
```

this is .htaccess file. now i want to make one url
like this: `domainname.com/seach/?name=Sameer&lastname=khan` etc.., With my Other Rule also work

**Edit**

This time "domainname.com/seach/,domainname.com/home/,domainname.com/contactus/" this url is working. now i want, when i submit form and i want use $_get method. thats why i need to send variable like: domainname.com/contactus/?name=Sameer&lastname=khan for this url my rule are not working they just give me in $_get or $_request only contactus

Comment: Clarify your requirement. What's wrong in `domainname.com/seach/?name=Sameer&lastname=khan` URL?

Comment: at this time **"domainname.com/seach/,domainname.com/home/,domainname.com/contactus/"** this url is working. now i want when i submit form and i want use $_get method that why i need to send variable **domainname.com/contactus/?name=Sameer&lastname=khan** for this url my rule are not working they just give me in $_get or $_request only contactus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use QSA flags in your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?urltype=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?urltype=$1&url=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?urltype=$1&url=$2&pages=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```